# What is this piece of TypeScript code doing?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, deprecated, react-hook-form

I am learning TypeScript and am still fairly new to it, and am attempting to digest this bit of code from the react-hook-form (library?) that is being deprecated.

I was lead to the declaration of this code as I am receiving the error

```
Argument of type 'UnpackNestedValue<PathValue<ControlType, Path<ControlType>>>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'PathValue<ControlType, Path<ControlType>>'.
```

Could someone kindly explain what it is doing?  I am struggling to make sense of it.

```
export declare type UnpackNestedValue<T> = T extends NestedValue<infer U> ? U : T extends Date | FileList | File | Blob ? T : T extends object ? {
[K in keyof T]: UnpackNestedValue<T[K]>;
} : T;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UnpackNestedValue with generic type input T **is type of**;

1. If T is of extended type of a NestedValue, say U, then **U**.
2. If not, then if T is of extended type of Date, FileList, File or Blob, then **T**.
3. If not, then if T is a non-primitive (object), then for each key of T, the types of respective values of T will be determined by the procedure defined starting from step 1.
4. If not, then T.

Note that step 3 initiates a recursion to resolve the types for values of T, if the condition in step 1 or step 2 does not hold.

Comment: Thanks so much!  Does this match the description of the process you described?  https://gyazo.com/0e345d69802dca9c7d97c316bd234934

Comment: exactly! you're welcome :)